# IOT simulation help testing protocols

Tags: java, iot, kura

If i set up an IOT simulation such as the greenhouse tutorial Kura how would I test the protocols MQTT and CoAP. How would I receive information such as speed, the amount of packets dropped, the traffic created etc. Are there any tools I could use.

http://iot.eclipse.org/java/tutorial/

thats the greenhouse page

I would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test and analyse any protocol information your best bet is to get [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which is free to use and is a pretty powerful networking tool in general.

This [article](https://iotprotocols.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/speedtests-in-a-simulated-iot-scenario-with-the-coap-protocol/) talks about using wireshark specifically for IoT protocol testing and should be plenty to get you going.